# Members with specific role

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, roles

When I use `role.members` bot returns me list`[<Member id=435088200919285762 name='CODEMAGIC®' discriminator='0001' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=726916686883586199 name='Indivisibility®' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=330>>]`
Can bot returns me **count** of members?(1, 2, 833...)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, role.members returns a list. Each element of this list are informations about every user in this role, if you want the count of members you may use `len(role.members)`

If you want to index every member in that role you may use enumerate()

```
for index, member in enumerate(role.members):
    print(index, member)
```